# How can you edit with shortcuts or macro, a string, in PHPStorm, breaking an array in keys array and values array

Tags: php, arrays, vim, phpstorm, text-editor

This is my first post, so here it goes.

I need to know how to do this in PHPStorm IDE. Not using PHP functions.

I have 3 types of arrays I need to work with, as illustrated in the following code:

```
$assoc= array(
    "some_key"=>"some_valuea",
    "some_keyasdasd"=>"some_valuesda",
    "some_keyasdasd"=>"assome_valuedaasd",
    "some_keaay"=>"asdsome_valueaasd",
    "some_keyad"=>"assome_valuedaasd",
    "some_keyaa"=>"some_valueasd",
    "some_keysdadas"=>"asome_valueasd",
    .
    .
    .
    );
$keys=array(
    "some_valuea",
    "some_valuesda",
    "assome_valuedaasd",
    "asdsome_valueaasd",
    "assome_valuedaasd",
    "some_valueasd",
    "asome_valueasd"
    .
    .
    .
    );
$values=array(
    "some_key",
    "some_keyasdasd",
    "some_keyasdasd",
    "some_keaay",
    "some_keyad",
    "some_keyaa",
    "some_keysdadas",
    .
    .
    .
    );
```

I am interested to know how I can create `$keys` and `$values` arrays in the text editor using a macro, or some automated way, by providing the `$assoc` array.
Also, I would like to know how to make the `$assoc` array if I have the other two arrays.

An example of what I am after, is in this tutorial, at minute 4:35.

I need a way to select all keys and just cut and be able to paste them as values, or as a new array.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScS8Q32lMxA

Comment: For your last question you need http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php. Buy why would you need to generate great amounts of data in arrays? Perhaps you are looking for a config file or a database?

Comment: @jeroen The OP refers to a function within his IDE, so some form of refactoring shortcut, not a php function at runtime.

Comment: @arkascha The combined array you can add automatically and for the other two; that's why I added the last part of my comment. The thing is I don't really see the point.

Comment: I need to know how to do this in my IDE. Not by using PHP code. If I write PHP code, I can just use array functions and is all done. I deal with legacy code and I have huge arrays and I need to be able to edit fast.

Comment: Then the first thing to do, is to get rid of the redundant data, you need *or* the two separate arrays *or* the combined one but never all three. Anyway, I don't know the editor so I don't have any answers.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such (very specific) functionality in IDE or plugins. Better write some custom script (e.g. PHP-powered one) that will do the job for you and then copy-paste results back into editor.

Comment: @jeroen You are right. That is what I am trying to do. But this situation happens in different places with different arrays, and having an automated way to break or merge such things, is helpful. Also, I see this useful in other circumstances. In CSS, HTML... Is a text editor feature that I have seen people use in VIM with great success. I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: I added a link to a video tutorial where something like what I want is performed in VIM.

Comment: Well -- multiple carets are available in PhpStorm: **1)** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Text+Editors#PhpStormforUsersofTextEditors-Multiplecaretsandselections%2FSublimestyleMultipleColumns **2)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged this question with `vim` so I assume a pure `vim` solution should also work for you.

The following procedure is not 100% automatic but is reasonably fast.

#### Splitting One Array into Two

1. Copy and paste the entire array twice. Rename the first copy to `$keys` and the second copy to `$values`.
2. Go to the first pair in the `$keys` array and (in normal mode) type `qq` to start recording a macro in the register `q`.
3. Type `0` to go to beginning of line, then `f>ldt,jq`.
   This says that we want to find the first instance of `>` on the line, go one character to the right, delete up to but not including the first `,` after that, and finally go down a line. We end the macro recording with `q` again.
4. Run the macro as many times as you have lines. For example, if you have 100 more lines, type `100@q`.
5. Go to the first pair in the `$values` and again type `qq`.
6. Type `0df>jq`.
7. Again, run the macro as many times as needed.

#### Joining Two Arrays.

The feature used in the video is called Visual Block Mode.
You can use it by typing `Control-v` in normal mode, and then selecting a block of text. You can then simply paste your block of values on the right of the block of keys to get the joined array.